# Hazelcast Mancenter rises cpu usage

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have:
**a)** 1 server (4vcpu, 8GB) running a hazelcast node,
**b)** 1 server (4vcpu, 8GB) running a hazelcast mancenter on tomcat 7.
Both servers are in the same local network.

I've tested 2 scenarios:
**Scenario 1)** I've started a) and b). No data transfered. The cpu usage on a) was 0-10%.
**Scenario 2)** I've started a) and b). I've transfered a bulk of data to process on a) and waited until it finished (2h). When no data was left to process I've checked the cpu usage on a) - it was 30-110% (even after 8h). When I stopped mancenter on b) the cpu on a) went down to 0-10%. After starting mancenter again it rose to 30-110%.

I think that the cpu usage on a) after 1) and 2) should be the same.

I've analized the jvm's and noticed that a thread called **MC.State.Sender** was inactive in scenario 1 and active in scenario 2. Could this be draining out the cpu? Can this be limited via configuration?

Thx in advance for any help.

Here are the thread dumps from visualvm (I can also provide cpu profiler snapshots):
[scenario1 thread dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_twqV_nSNG0TjJJbkxmRzRNNjg/view?usp=sharing)
[scenario2 thread dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_twqV_nSNG0RmpwNE1jQmdhMEE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: could you please share your hazelcast and management center versions?

Comment: Hazelcast is 3.4, Mancenter is 3.4.1, could this be the reason of the problem? I will try to check it.

Comment: I've repeated the tests with Hazelacast and Mancenter 3.4.1. So far the problem didn't repeat. I will test my solution for some more time. If the problem won't resurface I will resolve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the problem when using Hazelcast 3.4 and Mancenter 3.4.1.
After update'ing the Hazelcast lib to 3.4.1 I couldn't repeat the problem.

I was performing different tests for a whole week and the problem didn't occur again. 
The solution is to keep mancenter and Hazelcast lib in the same version.